# backup and restore app for databases

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, backup, mariadb, restore

I'm looking for an open source app to backup sql server / mariadb / postgres.
Do you know which app can do that ?
I want to schedule backups with the app.

yes it's possible with only one app . I used to schedule backups for my local databases servers ( SQL Server, mariaDB, Postgres) on SQLServerBackupAndFTP (it's an app) but unfortunately it's not free. that's why i'm looking for an open source tool.

Thank you guys.

Comment: Are your database systems running on Windows, Linux, or both? I assume they're all local, not cloud based?

Comment: Each of those platforms come with their own native tool to handle backup and restores of databases. Use those. If you're on Linux, then you can use cron jobs to schedule the backups. If you are on Windows, then you can use task scheduler or SQL Server Agent (for SQL Server) to schedule the backups.

Comment: Tivoli Storage Manager can cover all those databases but it certainly isn't open source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm looking for an open source app to backup sql server / mariadb / postgres.

One app?  *Singular*?
You won't find one.

Every DBMS does things *ever so slightly* differently from all the others.  Most significantly, each and every one has *its own* utilities for backing up and restoring its databases.

There is *no* "one size fits all" solution that will do *everything*.
As the Database Administrator, you have to know and understand *each one* of them.

> I want to schedule backups with the app.

Scheduling needs a scheduling program.  Almost any one will do.
Backing up each DBMS needs the utilities for that DBMS.
Restoring any database needs the utilities for that DBMS *and* is, usually, a manual activity.

Comment: yes it's possible with only one app . I used to schedule backups for my local databases servers ( SQL Server, mariaDB, Postgres) on SQLServerBackupAndFTP (it's an app) but unfortunately it's not free. that's why i'm looking for an open source tool.

Comment: @LucasRasolofoniaina I very much doubt that a program called `SQLServerBackupAndFTP ` creates a reliable backup of a running Postgres database. And if it does, it probably only copies the output of `pg_dump` to a FTP server - which is something any FTP tool can do. But the actual backup is take by `pg_dump` not by that FTP tool. And if you did not use `pg_dump`: did you ever test a restore of those backups to work properly? I would be surprised if that tool created unusable backups from Postgres

Comment: As ever, here we have a "Backup" product being touted as an "end" in itself, without /any/ mention of the /only/ reason that Backups exist - to be able to perform Recoveries from them!   (And yes, it uses pg_dump under the covers, so there's /no/ Point-in-Time recovery option for PostgreSQL).

Comment: if there's no way, so do we have to bakcup one by one every databases ? i have like 130 database servers to schedule there.

Comment: Yes, you need to backup every database.  How you do that is entirely up to you.  Each DBMS comes with utilities to do Backups.   What controls all this is your *Recovery* Strategy.  Note: not your "Backup" strategy - you shouldn't have one!  Backups are just tools that allow you to deliver your Recovery Strategy.  For each and every database, you and your business need to agree (1) How long you will have to get a "broken" database running again (RTO) and (2) How much Data you're allowed to /lose/ in doing that (RPO).  Then work out how to deliver that, which will /include/ Backups.